# Django form prefix with class based generic view

Tags: django, django-forms, django-generic-views

How can I set the form prefix keyword with the new class-based generic views in Django 1.3?  Setting the prefix prevents duplicate id in the rendered HTML.  This is documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms) for the forms API.

Since I have several different forms loaded using AJAX, I am running into problems with duplicate tags.

Comment: please clarify your question. the first sentence does not make sense to me. I mean forms are separate from views. what do you mean by "setting a form prefix with views"?

Comment: The form is a python class.  MyForm(prefix='myform1') would be an example of setting the keyword.  As described in the linked documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see your problem! You're trying to use `FormView`, which lets you specify `form_class`, but not a prefix.

I haven't tried this, but I suggest subclassing `FormView`, or whatever you're using, and overriding the `get_form_kwargs` method to add the prefix in.

You could do something like this:

```
class MyFormView(FormView):
    form_prefix = None

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(FormView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        if self.form_prefix:
            kwargs.update({'prefix': self.form_prefix})
        return kwargs
```

Then, I think, you'll be able to put `form_prefix` in the arguments to `MyFormView.as_view` in your urlconf.

As I say, I haven't tried this, but it might be worth a go - let me know if it works!

Comment: You could also do override 'get_prefix' method ;-)
Or you could also set the 'prefix' class attribute, if its non dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

I opened a ticket in django, with a patch attached, that modifies FormMixin, in order to make FormView behave like you wish.

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18872

Comment: Thank you very much. Here is the link to the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_prefix